# Regarding transfer of money

Tags: india, money-transfer, international-transfer

My daughter is staying in Singapore after marriage, with her husband (working there for four years) studied and is in job (more than one year). My son is to shift to Australia to pursue his MS course. Can she send money to me in India through their NRI account? Is it taxable for me?

Can I transfer this money for paying the fees of my son in Australia?

Answer (score 1):

> Can she send money to me in India through their NRI account?

She can transfer the money to her NRE account and then to your Savings Account. Alternatively she can also transfer money directly to your savings account.

There is no tax for this transaction in India as it is gift and exempt under gift tax act. If the amounts are large [run in quite a few tens of lacs], have some paperwork showing this as Gift.

You can transfer this to son or doing anything you like with it.